# Submit form on internet website

Tags: python

I want to build a python script to submit some form on internet website. Such as a form to publish automaticaly some item on site like ebay.

- Is it possible to do it with BeautifulSoup or this is only to parse some website?
- Is it possible to do it with selenium but quickly without open really the browser?
- Are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: 1) Nope. 2) Who knows. 3) Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.. Also, check out the chrome debugger toolbar to see the requests fly by. There is also a utility called [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), where you can "design", queries, then generate code in many different flavors (including pythons requests library).

BeautifulSoup is for parsing HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium with PhantomJS to do this without the browser opening. You have to use the Keys portion of selenium to send data to the form to be submitted.  It is also worth noting that this method will not work if there are captcha's on the form.

Answer (score 0):

The [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library can fill and submit forms.